# Is it legal to use an antonym of a trademark for a competing business's name?

Tags: united-states, trademark

If I started a chat service called Agreement, would I be in finding Discord's trademark?

Comment: Do you think it would cause confusion about the source of the service?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite probably not.

Comment: The standard is likelihood of confusion.